# count the values based on number of occurrences in the array object using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, loops, object

I have array of object, count the status using JavaScript

If object has started only / progress only / combination of started, progress / combination of started or progress with completed, cancelled
treated as started_progress count

If object has completed only treated as completed count

If object has cancelled only treated as cancelled count

If object has completed, cancelled together only treated as completed count

I've tried:

```js
var arrobj = [{
    id: 22,
    details: [{
        status: "started"
      },
      {
        status: "cancelled"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 24,
    details: [{
        status: "completed"
      },
      {
        status: "cancelled"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 44,
    details: [{
      status: "progress"
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 54,
    details: [{
        status: "progress"
      },
      {
        status: "completed"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 64,
    details: [{
      status: "cancelled"
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 74,
    details: [{
      status: "completed"
    }]
  }
];

var started_progress = arrobj.details.filter(e => ["started", "progress"].includes(e.status)).length;

var completed = arrobj.details.every(i => i.status === "completed").length;

var cancelled = arrobj.details.every(i => i.status === "cancelled").length;
```

Expected Output

```
started_progress = 3
completed = 2
cancelled = 1
```

Comment: You want `.filter()`, not `.every()`.

Comment: Array.every doesn’t return something with a meaningful length, it returns true or false.

Comment: I've formatted your posted code as a running snippet (so that it can be viewed in the question), please note that your posted code produces a type error: `arrobj.details is undefined` if this represents your current results that's fine, but if not please could you edit the code so that it's accurate to your own problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to reduce the array to an object containing the various counts.  You might have to adjust the big `if` block if the logic isn't quite right.

```js
var arrobj =[
  {id: 22, details: 
    [
     {status: "started"},
     {status: "cancelled"}
    ]
  },
  {id: 24, details: 
    [
     {status: "completed"},
     {status: "cancelled"}
    ]
  },
  { id: 44, details: 
    [
     {status: "progress"}
    ]
  },
  { id: 54, details: 
    [
     {status: "progress"},
     {status: "completed"}
    ]
  },
   { id: 64, details: 
    [
     {status: "cancelled"}
    ]
  },
   { id: 74, details: 
    [
     {status: "completed"}
    ]
  }
]

const output = arrobj.reduce((acc, el) => {
  if (el.details.length === 1 && el.details[0].status === "cancelled") {
    // only contains "cancelled"
    acc.cancelled++;
  } else if (el.details.length === 1 && el.details[0].status === "completed") {
    // only contains "completed"
    acc.completed++;
  } else if (el.details.length === 2 && el.details.find(d => d.status === "cancelled") && el.details.find(d => d.status === "completed")) {
    // only contains "completed" and "cancelled"
    acc.completed++;
  } else if (el.details.find(d => d.status === "progress" || d.status === "started")) {
    // contains "progress" or "started"
    acc.started_progress++;
  }
  return acc;
}, {
  started_progress: 0,
  completed: 0,
  cancelled: 0
});

console.log(output);
```